# Best Practise: (PHPUnit+Selenium) One login for all backend/restricted area tests

Tags: browser, cookies, selenium, phpunit

I am doing some functional tests for a backend plugin of magento. At the moment the browser profile is cleaned up between each test method (of my PHPUnit test) - so login is gone away between each test method.

It would be nice if i can do the login on a once-per-class basis to increase performance, but how to do that? How to keep the cookie in the browser and how to remove it after test class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't used Magento so my answer is more general. Can you supply a mock authentication object for the tests not directly related to it? Create a custom implementation to return `true` to every call to `isAuthenticated()` (or whatever the method is named).